# Sequelize find all and complex order by length of array and association

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I have a collection of posts.
Each post can have many likes, comments and can be shared by many users.
Each comment can also be liked by many users.

It's looking like this:

```js
let post = await PostModel.findAll({
   where: { _id: req.params.id },
   include : this.include
});
```

And the include is:

```js
this.include = 
[
    {
        model: UserModel,
        as: "likes",
        attributes: [
            "_id",
        ],
    },
    {
        model: CommentPostModel,
        as: "comments",
        attributes : ["_id"],
        include: [{
            model: UserModel,
            as: "likes",
            attributes: [
                "username",
            ],
        }]
}]
```

What I want is to be able to find the posts trending at X time.
(Time impact as the score.)

To be able to achieve this goal, I tried ordering like this:

```js
let top = 1 + (post.likes.length + (3 * post.shareBy.length));

if (post.comments) {
    top += 2 * post.comments.length ;
    let allReply = 0;
    for (let com of post.comments) {
        allReply += com.likes.length;
    }
    top += allReply;
}
const deltaTime = (new Date() - new Date(post.createdAt)) / 3600 / 1000;
post.trendIndicator = Math.floor((top * top) / (deltaTime / 168));
```

And to order by `post.trendIndicator`.

Currently what I do is:

I have a col `trendIndicator` in the `PostModel`. Each time a user interacts with the post, I calculate and update the score.

But if one post has 100000 in score and nobody interacts with the post, the score will be 10000 forever.

If someone knows if it's possible to do this, it will be very appreciable.

Comment: If time matters, you can create UDF(User Defined Functions) to calculate the score and call the function in ORDER query. Any major DB has an ability to add your UDF.  For postgres, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-user-defined-functions/.

Answer (score 0):

I think about one solution, if someone can help

**This is my model :**

```
const PostModel = sequelize.define( 'Post',
  {    
    _id : { primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4 },
    type : {
      allowNull : false,
      defaultValue : 'post',
      type : DataTypes.STRING(24)
    },
    text: {
      type : DataTypes.TEXT(),
      allowNull : true,
      validate: {
        len: {
           args: [0,1800],
           msg: "String length is not in this range [1-1800]"
      }
      }
    },
    privacy: {
      type : DataTypes.STRING(12),
      defaultValue : "public",
      allowNull : false
    },
    editTime: {
      type : DataTypes.DATE(),
      allowNull : true
    },
    shareBy: {
      type : DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING(58)),
      defaultValue: [],
    },
    trendIndicator: {
      type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 999,
      allowNull : false
    },
    gifLink: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(150),
      allowNull : true
    },
    pinned: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
    survey : {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull : true
    },
    latitude : {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull : true
    },
    longitude : {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      allowNull : true
    },
    views : {
      type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue : 0
    },
    tags : {
      type : DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING(50)),
      defaultValue: [],
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)
```

**What I Want to do**

```
let arrayOfPost = [id1,id2....]
await PostModel.update(
        { trendIndicator : Sequelize.literal('Length of comments array * 2 + Length of likes + Length of shareBy * 3 + views/3')}
        { where: { _id: arrayOfPost }}
      )
```